# Laravel: How to get method 'post' with link_to_action

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Is there anyway i can get link_to_action in the form of method 'post'?

**Here's my code**

```
{{ link_to_action('SummaryController@viewSummaryStudent', 'View Summary', array($students->student_id),
        array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}
```

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: You can't make HTML links that make a POST request. You have to use a form for that or JavaScript to make an ajax request

Comment: i see..... is there a code on how to use javascript for it? :c

Comment: I'm sure you'll find something online, but wait a second! `viewSummaryStudent` should definitely not be a POST route in my eyes. Or what's the reason for that?

Comment: oh im getting that as a post method for each students in my table  
Like, viewsummary for student1  something like that  

that's why im asking if there's anyway i can get a post method by this :/

Comment: But why not make it a GET route?

Comment: I did make it get route.... however, i have a section and subject that is also assigned to the student...  
Imagine if a student has many subject/sections to go to it would be hard...

In my code(I haven't shown it)  I have a 2 textbox that will indicate the section and subject for that student

Comment: Sorry I do not understand the problem. Maybe edit your question?

Comment: nvm i got it by using this... Thanks for the tip ^^
<button type="submit" formmethod="post" formaction="{{ URL::route('viewSummaryStudent') }}">

Comment: Check this gist by Jeffrey Way - https://gist.github.com/JeffreyWay/5112282. It designed for easy create links which produces `DELETE` and `PUT` requests. You can follow the idea to create links with emulation of `POST`.